# How do you scroll the tech tree screen in Civ 6?

Tags: civilization-6

I have tried edge scrolling, mouse keys, drag and pull - nothing works when I want to view more advanced civics or techs on the far right. It really makes planning your tech hard.

Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, the only way to scroll the tech/civic screens in Civilization 6 is to drag the scroll bar, which appears at the bottom of the screen.

Comment: The prevailing theory is that the team designing the tech tree interface got their start on a small island without mountains, and ended up two decades behind in science, hence the '90s scroll-bar functionality with no click-and-drag from the 2000s and no touchpad scrolling from the twentyteens.

Answer (score 1):

The scroll wheel on the mouse scrolls the tech screen.

At first, it felt a bit weird to scroll the wheel 'down' and see the screen move to the left, but I got used to it fast.